# How to enable and disable particular row in DataGridView by checkbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to enable and disable specific row in DataGridView by checking and unchecking of checkbox inside gridview. (C# Windows application)

I tried using the CellClick event which did not work as expected.

This is the code which i tried

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected == true)
    {

        dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = false;

    }

}
```

please tell me how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed the **CellContentClick** event, try this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{          
     if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Your Column Name"].Index) //To check that we are in the right column
     {
          dataGridView1.EndEdit();  //Stop editing of cell.
          if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Your Column Name"].Value)
          {
             //dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;// for entire column 
               int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
               int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
               dataGridView1.Rows[colIndex].Cells[rowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you for the answer. Can you please tell me how to make selected row cell to make ReadOnly = true;   if we put dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true; the whole column will become true. i dont want that

Comment: You can get    int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;  int rowIndex = e.RowIndex; for particular cell. I have edited the code

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use dataGridView "CellContentClick" event. The code goes as bellow.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var _dataGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    //Give your checkbox column Index
    int chkBoxColumnIndex = 1;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == chkBoxColumnIndex && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        bool isChecked = _dataGrid[chkBoxColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null ? false : (bool)_dataGrid[chkBoxColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            _dataGrid[i, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = isChecked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want only particular row which is checked to make read only...Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Oh, I thought column, you mention the column in your code.
I edit the code again, please check the code.

Comment: @user2924931 
Oh, I thought column, you mention the column in your code. I did edit the code again, please check the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're setting the readonly property to false meaning it is NOT read only. Try setting it to true. Also the event that fires this should be the checkbox click event (double click on the checkbox to create the event handler).

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Also, take a look at the frozen property.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[3].Frozen = true;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i have placed the checkbox within gridview. How to generate a event for that..

Comment: column index of the checkbox in gridview in "0"