# Disable selecting row in datagrid winforms c#

Tags: winforms, disable

I have a datagrid in winforms c# with some values and sometimes there would not not be value in a particular cell. I want to disable selecting such rows. The possible duplicate does not solve my issue as it does not stop me from selecting a row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable and disable particular row in DataGridView by checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529887/how-to-enable-and-disable-particular-row-in-datagridview-by-checkbox)

Comment: No sorry, i have tried it. :(